# Can dynamic_cast<Derived*>(static_cast<Base*>(voidPtr)) ever go wrong if voidPtr is null pointer or pointing to object that is inherited from Base?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism, language-lawyer

```
class Base {
    // ...
};

class Derived : public Base {
    // ...
};

class OtherDerived : public Base {
    // ...
};
```

If I know for a fact that `voidPtr` of type `void*` is a null pointer or pointing to an object of `Derived` or `OtherDerived`. Can `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(static_cast<Base*>(voidPtr))` return non-null pointer if `voidPtr` is pointing to an object of type `OtherDerived`

```
void someFunction(void* voidPtr) {
  auto derived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(static_cast<Base*>(voidPtr));
  if (derived == nullptr) {
    return;
  }

  // do something with derived
}
```

I came across with this problem when I was using Qt and its `void *QVariant::data()` function.

Comment: When multiple inheritance is involved, `Base` can be at nonzero offset in a derived class.

Comment: When you ask about _"unexpected results"_, please describe what you are expecting.

Comment: Also note having to use dynamic_cast (or static_cast to another class) at all in your code is usually a sign of a design problem in the first place. You should stick to a design that only uses virtual functions! And `void*` should hardly ever be needed in C++ either (unless in some library internal type erasure code, and if you don't know type erasure then don't use void*). So what are you trying to do?

Comment: "_If I know for a fact that voidPtr of type void* is a null pointer or pointing to an object of Derived or OtherDerived_": If you know that, then the code is very likely to have UB either way. You need `voidPtr` to be a pointer to a `Base` object, which may or not be a base class subobject of a `Derived` or `OtherDerived`. That's not the same. In particular converting a `DeriveD*` implicitly or with `static_cast` to `void*` will _not_ give you that.

Comment: "at all in your code is usually a sign of a design problem in the first place" Or you have things like a general event system with explicit handling for certain types - in which case dynamic-cast is the way to go.

Comment: Assuming this is called like `someFunction(static_cast<Base*>(otherDerivedPtr));`.  Otherwise, it's a very short step into UB territory without trying very hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(static_cast<Base*>(voidPtr))` ever go wrong if `voidPtr` is null pointer or pointing to object that is inherited from `Base`?

No, it will return `nullptr` or a pointer to a `Derived`. Only if `voidPtr` is *not* `nullptr` and is not actually pointing at a `Base` will there be problems (undefined behavior). Therefore, you must cast the `Derived*` to `Base*` in the call to `someFunction`.

Undefined behavior example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived : public Base {};
class OtherDerived : public Base {};

void someFunction(void* voidPtr) {
    // Undefined behavior:
    auto derived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(static_cast<Base*>(voidPtr));

    if (derived == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "fail\n";
        return;
    }
    // do something with derived
}

int main() {
    auto d = new Derived;
    someFunction(d); // should be `someFunction(static_cast<Base*>(d));`
    delete d;
}
```

> Can `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(static_cast<Base*>(voidPtr))` return non-null pointer if `voidPtr` is pointing to an object of type `OtherDerived`

No, not with the inheritance as you've defined it.

Comment: I guess it is important though that even if you replaced `new Foo` by `new Derived`, the code would still have UB. That might not be obvious.

Comment: @user17732522 Hmm, that was news to me. It'd be like going through `auto b = static_cast<Base*>(d);`. `auto derived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(b);` What's the problem with that?

Comment: It isn't the same. `static_cast<void*>(b)` is a pointer to the `Base` subobject, while `static_cast<void*>(d)` is a pointer to the `Derived` object. When you cast back from a `void*` with `static_cast` you must cast back to the type before the cast to `void*`, otherwise you get effectively something like `reinterpret_cast<Base*>(d)` which is wrong for the same reason. The `Base` base class subobject is generally (and in your example) not pointer-interconvertible with the `Derived` object and may not even be located at the same address.

Comment: @user17732522 Good thing I never do these things in real code :-) I need to read up on this.

Comment: Yes, such a function has no reason to take a `void*` instead of `Base*`. It _will_ cause some serious problems at some point and it will be hard to figure out where the problem is. The only correct way to call this function is to always insert a cast to `Base*` at the call site. Someone is eventually going to forget that. If it is really necessary, e.g. at a C interface, then OP should write a wrapper that takes a `Base*`, so that the implicit cast is done correctly.

Comment: @user17732522 some very neat tricks with meta-objects and type erasure are based on that, but that's usually a generated code. E.g. signal\slot system in Qt

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, I agree. I was thinking of removing the answer but realized that I didn't display my ignorance in the actual answer :-)